# MIPS convert an integer from [0, 511] into reverse order 3 bits octal

Tags: mips, octal

I need some help regarding an exercise of mine.
I have already created a program where I can convert any integer from [0, 31] into reverse order 5 bits binary. Here's the code

```
addi $9, $0, 27
addi $10, $0, 5
addi $2, $0, 1
L1:
and $4, $9, $2
syscall
srl $9, $9, 1
addi $10, $10, -1
bne $10, $0, L1
```

Now I need to do the same thing but as I mentioned in my post's title "convert an integer from [0, 511] into reverse order 3 bits octal"

Please try to be as simple as you can.
I am just a student not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of masking (`and`) with 1 (to isolate a single bit), mask with 7 (111 in binary) to isolate an octal digit; similarly, instead of shifting (`srl`) 1 place to *remove* the processed binary digit, shift it 3 places to remove the processed octal digit.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.
I have replaced the 3d line to `addi $2, $0, 7` and the 7th to `srl $9, $9, 3`.
When I run this in Mars I get a msg of "MIPS keyboard Input - Enter a double value(syscall7)".

Comment: You are using $2 for both the mask & the `syscall` selector; they used to be the same number (1), but no longer are.

Comment: So if I understood right, syscall cannot get value from $2 because the value has changed from 1 to 7? What I have to do fix that?

Comment: `syscall` *has* to get the value from $2 (that's how it is written), but you could use a different register for your mask.